# Django ValueError (The view views.save_flow_data didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

When I try to submit my form I get this message:

> The view views.save_flow_data didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

**Views.py**

```
def save_flow_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('upload_flow') \
        and request.POST.get('water_flow_rate')\
        and request.POST.get('water_flow_rate_unit')\
            data=CalcData()
            data.water_flow_rate = request.POST.get('water_flow_rate')
            data.water_flow_rate_unit = request.POST.get('water_flow_rate_unit')
            data.save()

            return render(request, 'io/flow.html')  

    else:
        return render(request,'io/flow.html')
```

**models.py**

```
class CalcData(models.Model):
    upload_flow = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    water_flow_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5)
    water_flow_rate_unit = models.TextChoices('wfr_unit', 'm3/day m3/month')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**submit button in form**

```
<div>
    <button action="{% url 'MyProject:save_flow_data' %}" type="submit" class="btn btn-light" style="width: 517.5px;" >Calculate</button>
</div>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='MyProject-home'),
path('io/flow/', views.io_flow, name='MyProject-io-flow'),
path('io/flow/save_flow_data', views.save_flow_data, name='save_flow_data')
]
```

I'm really not sure where to go from here. I had a perfectly working form but as soon as I scaled it up it flopped.

Comment: The case `if request.POST.get('upload_flow') and ...` is `False` is not covered, resulting in the function returning nothing (thus `None`)

Comment: @qcoumes How do I fix that? I'm not sure what other parameters to pass to the BooleanField

Comment: I answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove else statement and keep indentation of:
return render(request,'io/flow.html')
At function level.

Answer (score 1):

The case

```py
if request.POST.get('upload_flow') \
        and request.POST.get('water_flow_rate')\
        and request.POST.get('water_flow_rate_unit')\
```

is False is not covered.

You need to either remove the last `else` :

```py
def save_flow_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('upload_flow') \
        and request.POST.get('water_flow_rate')\
        and request.POST.get('water_flow_rate_unit')\
            data=CalcData()
            data.water_flow_rate = request.POST.get('water_flow_rate')
            data.water_flow_rate_unit = request.POST.get('water_flow_rate_unit')
            data.save()

            return render(request, 'io/flow.html')  

    return render(request,'io/flow.html')
```

Or add a `return` to the uncovered path:

```py
def save_flow_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('upload_flow') \
        and request.POST.get('water_flow_rate')\
        and request.POST.get('water_flow_rate_unit')\
            data=CalcData()
            data.water_flow_rate = request.POST.get('water_flow_rate')
            data.water_flow_rate_unit = request.POST.get('water_flow_rate_unit')
            data.save()

            return render(request, 'io/flow.html')

        return render(request, 'io/flow.html')  # Or return something else

    else:
        return render(request,'io/flow.html')
```